# Unable to start eclipse via shortcut

Tags: eclipse

I get an error "Java started but returned with an exit code=1"
when i start my eclpse..

Below is the content of my eclipse.ini file.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` to eclipse.ini and check out if it works.

Obviously, you need to remove the last line `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`.

If you still get the problems then try to run the application as administrator.

Secondly, How much JVM you have: **32-bit or 64-bit JVM**?

And which version of eclipse did you downloaded: **32 bit or 64-bit eclipse**?

They both must be same bitwise for compatiblity.

Comment: Tried adding the -XX:+UseCompressedOops after removing the last line. Does not work.

Comment: Already tried this so did not help, still see the issue.How do i see the if i have JVM 32 or 64 bit. Also how do i figure out if i have Eclipse 32 or 64 bit. Also noticed that i don't have this entry in my eclipse.ini file -vm c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe. Do i need this. If yes seems like I have multipel versions of the javaw.exe file from different JDks', which javaw.exe should i be using.